# breezejs : Model metadata incomplete

Tags: breeze

I've noticed that if I do the following in my C# model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Le numéro de police est requis.")]
public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
```

the error message is not passed along with the metadata. That's annoying because it means I have to redefine all of my custom messages on the client side. Is there anyway to pass this information with the metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does not yet convert .NET Validation attributes to Breeze validations. But it is a very reasonable request.  Please add this to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take this venue very seriously in determining what to work on next... and thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this for my project.
What I have done is downloaded the source code for EFContextProvider. Then change the code in BuildJsonMetadata() so that it uses reflection to produce the metadata string using JSON.NET objects.